# what is the Difference between Bit masks and bit manipulation?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitmask

any one can give me answer to this Question ! is **Bit Masks** and **Bit Manipulation** are same topics ? or different ?

Comment: masks is a subset of manipulation, being a specific type of manipulation.

Comment: Ok :)) @MadPhysicist
can you give me good resources to study bit manipulation  from it ?
thanks for your kind :)

Comment: No worries. I would start with just googling "bit manipulation tutorial" or "introduction to bit manipulation". C is probably a good language to start with, but Java, Python and many others use the same set of operations.

Comment: Also, just as an FYI, SO is a site for specific programming questions. It is not really a good place for this type of question, which is why I voted to close. That being said, good luck in your learning.

Comment: Bit manipulation is somewhat about to manipulate the bits in a numeric value. And this process is usually done through a mask of bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitmasks are a type of bit manipulation, usually performed using the bitwise AND operator to read or clear a specific number of bits. It can also refer to setting, clearing, and toggling individual bits in a bit field. Good resources for learning about bit manipulation (as you requested): [Bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation), [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html), [Bit manipulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation), and [Masks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)).